# How To Use style sheet (.css) file in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

[image]

I am New to ASP.NET So please help me How To Use Elements And @Blocks 
1.I know How to Use Class `<div class="Header">Any Text</div>`
2.I Know How to use Element id `<div id="Header">Any Text</div>`
But
3.Elements ????
4.@Blocks ???

Comment: describe your question clearly. it is confusing

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing, and simply not at a high enough standard for Stackoverflow.  We are not a tutorial... we are here to help with specific technical problems, where you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Refer the style sheet on the top header like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean under "elements" and @blocks? Elements in html open with start tag, for example  Any content here . If you mean Razor syntax under @block you should read books.